# python script client side of web application to control hardware

Tags: python, client, execute

i'm looking for how to execute a python script on the client side of a web application that would, of course, run outside of the browser (say in the shell of a raspberry pi) in order to control some hardware.  i'd then use the data collected by the hardware to then save to the mysql database used in the web application back on the server side.  anybody know the best method how to go about doing this?  and if so,  may i get an example of some code after hitting html button to execute the script?

Comment: Without more details, it would be hard to suggest a solution.  How are the RPi and server connected, is it local/private or over the internet, how much data is there, how fast is the data coming, how fast does the RPi need to react to commands from the server, etc.

Comment: RPi used for web browsing to web server through website.  RPi also use for ADB android phone connection for camera capture to send data to website server for image processing for image return to browser.